# Interfacing 5V to 3V3 devices - MAX3377 damaging my board

Tags: spi, level-shifting, 5v, 3.3v, maximum-ratings

I am using the bidirectional [MAX3377](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3372E-MAX3393E.pdf) level translator by maxim. I am doing a prototype board and as I test this board piece by piece, everything works until I solder on this part, and my 3v3 rated microcontroller begins to fail.

[image: Level Shifter]

[image: PCB layout]

[image: PCB layout]

The low and high side of the boards are appropriately isolated, yet some damage is caused to the chip as soon as i solder on these two level shifters. This has occurred on 3 of my prototype boards already

Could anyone explain why this could be happening? Is it something to do with the 3 state pin? I only have one prototype PCB left, help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Vusb? You have a power rail tied to a pin? It's not a voltage regulator. Did you check for shorts?

Comment: Could VUSB ever exceed the +5V supply (e.g. when USB is first attached and the +5V supply is not yet fully on)?

Comment: The `THREE-STATE` pin is referenced to the VL logic supply, so connecting it directly to 3V3 supply (VL) should be OK.

Comment: VUSB does not power the board, its just there to tell the microcontroller that it is plugged in. Also, no USB device was plugged in at any time as I have not reached that part of testing the board yet.

Comment: Where are the nearest bypass capacitors for the +5V (VCC) supply? If it's on the other side of the PCB that may be OK, but bypass capacitors need to be fairly local (e.g. 10mm-20mm) to do much actual good.

Comment: about 30mm away where the 5v regulator is

Comment: Not an answer, but some advice: now that you've isolated the problem, try to prototype with _just_ the level translators (and power supplies) populated.  You can simply touch wires to the inputs and read the outputs with a multimeter.  This should help you figure out the problem.  Since you only have one PCB remaining you may wish to remove everything from a failed board to do your testing.

Comment: Ignore my comment (deleted) about the footprint - I was reading the pin-out for the DFN package not the TSSOP package.

Comment: Is your microcontroller programmed or just sitting there in an unprogrammed state? Also, SPI doesn't require bidirectional lines, so the ideal solution might be to just scrap this part and use unidirectional translators.

Comment: If there is no 5V then it can't be power sequence 5> 3.3 latch up. but if chip is unpowered on 5V side , this should not load the uC 3.3V side,  Did uC get hot?

Comment: @bitsmack - The level shifters work as intended once they are on the board, however once soldered on my uC (atxmega128a1) no longer has a functional USART and continues to not function if I desolder them. It's seemingly unrelated but its happened 3 times without me changing anything else!

Comment: @The Photon - its programmed, i am testing its functionality one by one as i solder things onto the board. If i cant figure this out, itll have to be swapped for some sort transistor arrangement

Comment: @TonyStewart - Chip did not get hot. USART just dies.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question and further comments to it properly, something in ATMega fries and then MCU pins, connected to the MAX3377, stop working.

It is logical to suppose that it happens due to some physical event affecting MCU pins. Most probably that MCU, at some point in time, has pin configured as output, and MAX3377 also tries to output some voltage, and MAX having better protection on the over-current than MCU. For example, MCU outputs logical 0, but MAX, for some reason thinking that it should translate from other side of its row, puts +3V3 onto the same line. Or vice versa. I can only guess, given that you soldered everything properly and there're no shortages.

Side note on the top drawing of MAX3377. Please try to avoid mirrored drawing of power supply symbol (you have 3V3 mirrored down) so that it looks like ground sign.

Conclusion: look into MCU's datasheet to see which I/O state its pins have on power on (the moment when level conflict may happen), and the sequence of port initialization to ensure that the first thing microcode does is to assign input state to input pins and output to output pins.

But in general, as The Photon advised, stop using bidirectional translators which use bias for its decision making; use unidirectionals or controlled bidirectionals (e.g. 74LVC_256 family)

Just to add: in my opinion Maxim's sheet for this device is lacking some vital information, looking more like marketing material, and I personally would not use this device in my designs, at least without close support from Maxim.